# One or more operations in the bulk request did not complete successfully

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, testing, phpunit

Using the elastic in Laravel application, when I update a model on running feature testing, got this error:

> In my controller:
> $model->update($input);

**$model is indexing in elasticsearch engin.**

```
(ElasticAdapter\\Exceptions\\BulkRequestException(code: 0): One or more operations in the bulk request did not complete successfully at /var/www/html/vendor/babenkoivan/elastic-adapter/src/Documents/DocumentManager.php:51)
```

Used packages is:

```
babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver
babenkoivan/elastic-migrations
```

I was expecting everything done successfully

Comment: Would be useful to link what library you are using and what you're trying to do otherwise this question lacks context

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation I run this command and everything done successfully.

```
php artisan elastic:migrate:fresh
```